# How do I fix "An email message can’t be created because Safari can’t find an email application."?

Tags: macos, safari, email

I have both Safari and Mail installed - ever since a fresh OSX Lion install. Also, I have never removed or reinstalled them or messed around with them. So this "error" message is quite a surprise to me.

[image: An email message can’t be created because Safari can’t find an email application.]

How do I fix this?

Comment: In Terminal, does `open -a Mail` work?

Comment: @lhf Yes. `Mail.app` opens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Mail.app `Preferences > General > Default email reader` pop-up menu:

[image: ScreenShot of Mail.app Preferences]

If this doesn't work:

- Select a different mail client
- Close Preferences
- Reopen Preferences and re-select Mail.app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have set `Mail.app` 5.2 as the default Email reader already.

Comment: But you didn't indicate that in your original posting, gentmatt, or I wouldn't have suggest this solution!

Comment: Have you gone back to Preferences, selected any another client, closed & reopened Preferences, then re-reset it to Mail.app?

Comment: Buya! That's it! Thank you and please add this info to your answer. ;)